# Including an embedded web server - possible issues with deployment

Tags: apache, iis, deployment, web-applications

While analyzing some approaches to making our web app easier to deploy on our customers' sites, one of the suggestions was to include an embeddable web server to save the customer from needing to configure/install Apache/IIS.

What are some drawbacks to this approach? Specifically, what are the possible issues that we could come across with an embeddable web server if the customer's server already has Apache/IIS running on the default port?

Have you seen this approach taken by any commercial products? If the goal is easier deployment with the least amount of "server surgery" needed during installation, is embedding a web server a viable approach? Or are there more beneficial ways to minimize deployment support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think one big drawback might be that they're going to be inheriting whatever security holes or default settings for Apache / IIS which are being brought in with the embeddable web server.  If it's going to be locked down by a savvy network admin, accessed by a limited number of users or machines, etc., that's a different story, but if it's just going to be plopped on the network and visible and consumable to everyone who happens by that's a potential red flag.

Along with that you might also get stuck with upgrade issues, like if Apache or IIS, or some subcomponent your application requires like OpenSSL for example has some update come along to plug a security hole, will you then opt not to disrupt your customer's production environment because they're "most likely" not going to be a victim of that hole, or will you mandate that they upgrade or else you won't take responsibility for the consequences (even though, you whisper to yourself, you put them in that situation in the first place).

The only commercial products I've seen that do this in my limited experience are web appliance and router makers like Linksys, Sonic, Cisco, etc., with their onboard web interface.  Usually though those devices are working with set and well-defined protocols and processes, whereas your application might not be so well-defined or straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

If your OS is Windows 2008+ ie, IIS7+ then you have the option to use IIS Hostable Webcore.

The whole webserver is implemented inside hwebcore.dll, which is installed with IIS7 and selectable for IIS7.5 (Win2k8 R2).

You can find article and code sample from here which I wrote long ago... check it out
http://www.awesomeideas.net/page/IIS7-Hostable-WebCore.aspx

Another option is WebMatrix if it's just for development purpose.